# Identify server_ip of calling script

Tags: php, environment-variables

I've googled and searched, without success :(

I have some php and perl scripts calling a responding php script.
The calling scripts generate web page output and the responding php script interrogates the DB and returns json data to those calling scripts so they can show the results from the db.

The calling scripts send their call via ajax.

I need to ensure only web pages located on my server can allow access to the php responding scripts.

Do the cross-site scripting rules prevent (ajax) scripts on other servers connecting with my responding script?

The following are updates to clarify where your collective help here has moved me on to.

OK, so I get CORS.
I want to preventing everything from accessing the responding php script except my own ajax request.

For ajax, I shall send a token that will be checked by the responding php script for a match in the db. If there is a match, the query for the ajax call is made and returned. If no match, the script dies?
For Curl and/or any direct access through a browser I can still use the token method but also, can check the remote ip address to make sure it is that of my own server only. Yes?

Comment: AJAX requests are made from the _client_, the server where that script code originally came from is not involved _at all_ here. What you are asking for, does not even exist.

Comment: Go read up on CORS. (But be aware that that applies to client-side requests only in the first place. This is not going to stop anyone who knows your PHP URL from requesting the data from a different context.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that now.  Of course, the url of the php (responding script), is in the js on the web page sending the ajax call.

Comment: I've updated the end of my OP with a question reflective of my progressive learning.  I hope that's a clean way to develop my post, for the benefit of others later?

Comment: It really depends against what exactly you want to protect here. CORS only affects requests made using client-side scripting languages, such as AJAX requests made via JavaScript. But that does not apply, if I make the request using cURL, or PHP - or just my browser, by putting the URL to your PHP script directly into my browser address bar. If you want to protect against that as well, then you need something more, like a token for example, yes.

Comment: cURL or other server-side requests you can identify by your server IP, yes. The browser, when you simply call the URL via the address bar, would have to be running _on_ the server machine for the same test to work, of course. (But since you mainly want to _reject_ those requests, that doesn’t matter much here either.)

Comment: Thank you, again.

Answer (score -1):

you can user this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ip = "<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?>";
    alert(ip);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Using Javascript for security features does not look good to me